# Get random object from JSON, then get another random object from this object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I'm trying to show random banners to users. I have two types of ads, image and sliders. I want randomly choose one of them and then also randomly choose one ad from previously chosen ad type. So I want to randomly get `imageAds` or `sliderAds` object and then also randomly get one child object of selected `imageAds` or `sliderAds`.

Here is my JSON:

```
var campaign = {
    imageAds: {
        imageAd1: {
            img: 'imageAd1/imageURL',
            button: {
                text: 'imageAd1 button text',
                link: 'imageAd1 button link',
                color: '#fff',
            },
            headline: {
                text: 'imageAd1 headline',
                color: '#fff',
            },
            spots: {
                spot1: {
                    img: 'spot1 img',
                    text: 'spot1 text',
                    color: '#fff',
                },
                spot2: {
                    img: 'spot2 img',
                    text: 'spot2 text',
                    color: '#fff',
                },
                spot3: {
                    img: 'spot3 img',
                    text: 'spot3 text',
                    color: '#fff',
                },
            },
            footer: {
                text: 'imageAd1 footer',
                color: '#fff',
            },
        },
        imageAd2: {
            img: 'imageAd2/imageURL',
            button: {
                text: 'imageAd2 button text',
                link: 'imageAd2 button link',
                color: '#fff',
            },
            headline: {
                text: 'imageAd2 headline',
                color: '#fff',
            },
            spots: {
                spot1: {
                    img: 'spot1 img',
                    text: 'spot1 text',
                    color: '#fff',
                },
                spot2: {
                    img: 'spot2 img',
                    text: 'spot2 text',
                    color: '#fff',
                },
                spot3: {
                    img: 'spot3 img',
                    text: 'spot3 text',
                    color: '#fff',
                },
            },
            footer: {
                text: 'imageAd2 footer',
                color: '#fff',
            },
        },
    }, 
    sliderAds: {
        sliderAd1: {
            slide1: {
                img: 'slide1/imageURL',
                button: {
                    text: 'slide1 button text',
                    link: 'slide1 button link',
                    color: '#fff',
                },
                headline: {
                    text: 'slide1 headline',
                    color: '#fff',
                },
                spots: {
                    spot1: {
                        img: 'spot1 img',
                        text: 'spot1 text',
                        color: '#fff',
                    },
                    spot2: {
                        img: 'spot2 img',
                        text: 'spot2 text',
                        color: '#fff',
                    },
                    spot3: {
                        img: 'spot3 img',
                        text: 'spot3 text',
                        color: '#fff',
                    },
                },
                footer: {
                    text: 'slide1 footer',
                    color: '#fff',
                },
            },
            slide2: {
                img: 'slide2/imageURL',
                button: {
                    text: 'slide2 button text',
                    link: 'slide2 button link',
                    color: '#fff',
                },
                headline: {
                    text: 'slide2 headline',
                    color: '#fff',
                },
                spots: {
                    spot1: {
                        img: 'spot1 img',
                        text: 'spot1 text',
                        color: '#fff',
                    },
                    spot2: {
                        img: 'spot2 img',
                        text: 'spot2 text',
                        color: '#fff',
                    },
                    spot3: {
                        img: 'spot3 img',
                        text: 'spot3 text',
                        color: '#fff',
                    },
                },
                footer: {
                    text: 'slide2 footer',
                    color: '#fff',
                },
            },
        },
        sliderAd2: {
            slide1: {
                img: 'slide1/imageURL',
                button: {
                    text: 'slide1 button text',
                    link: 'slide1 button link',
                    color: '#fff',
                },
                headline: {
                    text: 'slide1 headline',
                    color: '#fff',
                },
                spots: {
                    spot1: {
                        img: 'spot1 img',
                        text: 'spot1 text',
                        color: '#fff',
                    },
                    spot2: {
                        img: 'spot2 img',
                        text: 'spot2 text',
                        color: '#fff',
                    },
                    spot3: {
                        img: 'spot3 img',
                        text: 'spot3 text',
                        color: '#fff',
                    },
                },
                footer: {
                    text: 'slide1 footer',
                    color: '#fff',
                },
            },
            slide2: {
                img: 'slide2/imageURL',
                button: {
                    text: 'slide2 button text',
                    link: 'slide2 button link',
                    color: '#fff',
                },
                headline: {
                    text: 'slide2 headline',
                    color: '#fff',
                },
                spots: {
                    spot1: {
                        img: 'spot1 img',
                        text: 'spot1 text',
                        color: '#fff',
                    },
                    spot2: {
                        img: 'spot2 img',
                        text: 'spot2 text',
                        color: '#fff',
                    },
                    spot3: {
                        img: 'spot3 img',
                        text: 'spot3 text',
                        color: '#fff',
                    },
                },
                footer: {
                    text: 'slide2 footer',
                    color: '#fff',
                },
            },
        },
    },
};
```

Currently I'm able to get `imageAds` or `sliderAds`, but I'm failing to randomly get their child objects. Here is my current code:

```
var properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(campaign);
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * properties.length);
var adType = {};
adType[properties[index]] = campaign[properties[index]];
// output: imageAds or sliderAds object

var properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(adType);
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * properties.length);
var ad = {};
ad[properties[index]] = adType[properties[index]];
// Expected output: imageAd1, imageAd2, sliderAd1 or sliderAd2
// Actual output: imageAds or sliderAds object

console.log(ad);
```

So how can handle this?

Comment: Some places you wrote `propertiesi` instead `properties `

Comment: @andergtk Sorry for that typo, fixed it, but the problem is still there. The code doesn't work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Made also short test as 0/1 random may not show all options ;-):

```js
function demo (index1, index2) {
    var properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(campaign);
    var index = index1 === undefined ? Math.floor(Math.random() * properties.length)
        : index1;
    var adType = campaign[properties[index]];
    console.log(index, properties[index]);

    properties = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(adType);
    index = index2 === undefined ? Math.floor(Math.random() * properties.length)
        : index2;
    var ad = { };
    ad[properties[index]] = adType[properties[index]];
    console.log(index, JSON.stringify(ad).substr(0, 100));
}
function test () {
    console.log('Random:');
    demo(); // random
    console.log('0,0');
    demo(0, 0);
    console.log('1,0');
    demo(1, 0);
    console.log('0,1');
    demo(0, 1);
    console.log('1,1');
    demo(1, 1);
}
var campaign = {
    imageAds: {
        imageAd1: {
            img: 'imageAd1/imageURL',
            button: {
                text: 'imageAd1 button text',
                link: 'imageAd1 button link',
                color: '#fff'
            },
            headline: {
                text: 'imageAd1 headline',
                color: '#fff'
            },
            spots: {
                spot1: {
                    img: 'spot1 img',
                    text: 'spot1 text',
                    color: '#fff'
                },
                spot2: {
                    img: 'spot2 img',
                    text: 'spot2 text',
                    color: '#fff'
                },
                spot3: {
                    img: 'spot3 img',
                    text: 'spot3 text',
                    color: '#fff'
                }
            },
            footer: {
                text: 'imageAd1 footer',
                color: '#fff'
            }
        },
        imageAd2: {
            img: 'imageAd2/imageURL',
            button: {
                text: 'imageAd2 button text',
                link: 'imageAd2 button link',
                color: '#fff'
            },
            headline: {
                text: 'imageAd2 headline',
                color: '#fff'
            },
            spots: {
                spot1: {
                    img: 'spot1 img',
                    text: 'spot1 text',
                    color: '#fff'
                },
                spot2: {
                    img: 'spot2 img',
                    text: 'spot2 text',
                    color: '#fff'
                },
                spot3: {
                    img: 'spot3 img',
                    text: 'spot3 text',
                    color: '#fff'
                }
            },
            footer: {
                text: 'imageAd2 footer',
                color: '#fff'
            }
        }
    },
    sliderAds: {
        sliderAd1: {
            slide1: {
                img: 'slide1/imageURL',
                button: {
                    text: 'slide1 button text',
                    link: 'slide1 button link',
                    color: '#fff'
                },
                headline: {
                    text: 'slide1 headline',
                    color: '#fff'
                },
                spots: {
                    spot1: {
                        img: 'spot1 img',
                        text: 'spot1 text',
                        color: '#fff'
                    },
                    spot2: {
                        img: 'spot2 img',
                        text: 'spot2 text',
                        color: '#fff'
                    },
                    spot3: {
                        img: 'spot3 img',
                        text: 'spot3 text',
                        color: '#fff'
                    }
                },
                footer: {
                    text: 'slide1 footer',
                    color: '#fff'
                }
            },
            slide2: {
                img: 'slide2/imageURL',
                button: {
                    text: 'slide2 button text',
                    link: 'slide2 button link',
                    color: '#fff'
                },
                headline: {
                    text: 'slide2 headline',
                    color: '#fff'
                },
                spots: {
                    spot1: {
                        img: 'spot1 img',
                        text: 'spot1 text',
                        color: '#fff'
                    },
                    spot2: {
                        img: 'spot2 img',
                        text: 'spot2 text',
                        color: '#fff'
                    },
                    spot3: {
                        img: 'spot3 img',
                        text: 'spot3 text',
                        color: '#fff'
                    }
                },
                footer: {
                    text: 'slide2 footer',
                    color: '#fff'
                }
            }
        },
        sliderAd2: {
            slide1: {
                img: 'slide1/imageURL',
                button: {
                    text: 'slide1 button text',
                    link: 'slide1 button link',
                    color: '#fff'
                },
                headline: {
                    text: 'slide1 headline',
                    color: '#fff'
                },
                spots: {
                    spot1: {
                        img: 'spot1 img',
                        text: 'spot1 text',
                        color: '#fff'
                    },
                    spot2: {
                        img: 'spot2 img',
                        text: 'spot2 text',
                        color: '#fff'
                    },
                    spot3: {
                        img: 'spot3 img',
                        text: 'spot3 text',
                        color: '#fff'
                    }
                },
                footer: {
                    text: 'slide1 footer',
                    color: '#fff'
                }
            },
            slide2: {
                img: 'slide2/imageURL',
                button: {
                    text: 'slide2 button text',
                    link: 'slide2 button link',
                    color: '#fff'
                },
                headline: {
                    text: 'slide2 headline',
                    color: '#fff'
                },
                spots: {
                    spot1: {
                        img: 'spot1 img',
                        text: 'spot1 text',
                        color: '#fff'
                    },
                    spot2: {
                        img: 'spot2 img',
                        text: 'spot2 text',
                        color: '#fff'
                    },
                    spot3: {
                        img: 'spot3 img',
                        text: 'spot3 text',
                        color: '#fff'
                    }
                },
                footer: {
                    text: 'slide2 footer',
                    color: '#fff'
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
test();
```